# Kivy Popup change background

Tags: python, popup, kivy, background-color

Im not sure why, but when i want to change my popup-background (which i create in python, not kivy), i change the background of the whole screen except my actual popup. My code looks like this (broken down a lot):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window

class BoxL(BoxLayout):
    def chooseFile(self):
        self.chosePop = Popup()
        self.chosePop.title = 'My Popup'
        choseBox = BoxLayout()
        choseBoxLabel = Label()
        choseBoxLabel.text = 'Any Text'
        choseBox.add_widget(choseBoxLabel)
        self.chosePop.content = choseBox
        self.chosePop.background_normal = ''
        self.chosePop.background_color = 0.5, 0.75, 0, 0.75
        self.chosePop.open()

class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MyApp'
        return BoxL()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

what i also tried was this:

```
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

class BoxL(BoxLayout):
    def chooseFile(self):
        with self.chosePop.canvas:
             Color(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75)
             Rectangle(pos=choseBox.pos, size=choseBox.size)
             #Rectangle(pos=self.chosePop.pos, size=self.chosePop.size) #this brings the correct size but at a wrong position, and the original popup background doesnt get changed either)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think this is really simple. My answer over complicates the issue. I believe all you need is to add the line:

```
self.chosePop.opacity = 0.5
```

right after you create the `Popup`.

Comment: Ah, amazing, thank you !! Thats what i was looking for :))

Answer (score 0):

In your `Popup`, most of what you see is the background of the `Labels`. One `Label` is the `title`, and the other is your `ChooseBoxLabel`. You can easily adjust the background color of the `ChooseBoxLabel`, by using a custom class with a `kv` rule to create a colored `Rectangle` for the background. The `title` `Label` is more difficult, since the developer of `Popup` didn't any way to access that `title` background color.

Here is an example of some things you can do:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<Label>:  # Note that this affects EVERY Label in the app
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<MyBoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')

class BoxL(BoxLayout):
    def chooseFile(self):
        self.chosePop = Popup()
        self.chosePop.title = 'My Popup'
        choseBox = MyBoxLayout()
        choseBoxLabel = Label()
        choseBoxLabel.size_hint_y = 0.2
        choseBoxLabel.text = 'Any Text'
        choseBox.add_widget(choseBoxLabel)
        self.chosePop.content = choseBox
        self.chosePop.size_hint = (.5, .5)
        self.chosePop.open()

class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MyApp'
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_popup, 3)
        return BoxL()

    def do_popup(self, dt):
        self.root.chooseFile()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

In the above code, the `MyBoxLayout` custom class provides a blue background which is only visible if the `Label` in it is not filling the `Layout`. The `Label` rule in the `kv` provides a background color for the `title` and the `chooseBoxLabel`, but it will affect every `Label` in the `App`.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Everything works as intended, however this doesnt seem to fit my purpose. Also i want to make the whole popup background 50% transparent, with your method it seems like i only reduce the opacity of the color on top while there is still a background behind it. There must be a way to just set the backgroundcolor and background_normal of the whole popup from python-side properly.. But thank you alot for taking your time!